# What does "Enable Strict URLs" really mean?

Tags: templates, settings

What does "Enable Strict URLs" really mean and are there any security/other implications if I choose to not use strict URLs?

Comment: +1. I still have no idea what this actually does, but I always enable it because it sounds like a good thing :)

Comment: I end up doing the same though it does have one annoying side effect: http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html#strict-urls

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My URL schematic points out the difference it makes to the regular flow - might be helpful:

http://www.jamessmith.co.uk/articles/expressionengine_url_schematic

As you can see from the diagram, it prevents EE from determining a template via <del>methods #2 and #4</del> method #2 as numbered there (and as alluded to in the other answers).

For me the benefit of more reliable 404's doesn't outweigh the advantage of being able to determine a template in <del>these ways</del> this way, so I never enable it.

[answer corrected May 2013 - You CAN have Strict URLs turned on and still use method #4.]

Comment: Awesome! totally forgot about that schematic. We should add that to the wiki here.

Comment: That schematic is going to be added to my debug toolbox. Thanks James pure gold.

Comment: My pleasure. @CreateSean what and where is there a wiki here? Can't see that anywhere? It's a strange old game this Stack Exchange malarkey.

Comment: James, there's supposed to be a wiki, but I haven't figured it out yet. might be something that happens when we have users with higher rep.

Answer (score 9):

With [Strict URLs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html#strict-urls) off, if your first segment doesn't correspond to an existing template group, EE will then look for a template with the same name in your *default* template group, and render that template if found.

Enabling Strict URLs prevents the behaviour - if `{segment_1}` is not a template group (and your URL is not a Pages URL), you'll get a 404.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding of strict urls is as follows:

Lets say you have a news template/channel.

if you go to site.com/news/ this (assuming you've coded it so) will show you a list of all news items on the page.

You now have a site.com/news/view/url_title_here which is a single list page based on the last segment being the URL_TITLE of the news item.

My understanding with strict URL's is that if you were to go to site.com/news/view/ without strict url's being enabled, it would simply show the 'latest' news item - however with it enabled, it will error/404.

At least thats always been my understanding.

Comment: That's basically how I understand it too.

Comment: There's an additional effect of enabling strict URLs that has caught me out before: with it **on**, you can view templates in your default template group directly by template name, without specifying the group in the URL, eg: `example.com/template_name`, whereas with it off you cannot, and must access them as `example.com/template_group/template_name`.

Comment: Tom - I think you mean that in reverse? Strict URLs *on* means that you *always* need to specify the template group.

Comment: @madebyhippo - this is actually not true. This behaviour only occurs if you specify `require_entry="yes"` in your Channel Entries tag, and then you add `{if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}`. Strict URLs has no effect on the scenario you describe.

Comment: @DerekHogue, you're quite right - will amend my comment

Answer (score 1):

Backing up a little: My understanding is that Strict URL's were implemented because of duplicate content* issues - duplicate content is rarely an issue at all anyway. Google will just decide to index 1 page. It would be possible to run into a canonical issues but again that's rare.

- Different duplicate content than copying other sites and trying to out rank for that content.

Personally i don't run strict urls as it makes url's ugly although- by reading above i need to revisit and test a few things for clarification in my mind how exactly it works.