# Strict URLs / Removing one template group name

Tags: htaccess

I would like to have 'strict URLs' enabled, but see I have to include the template group name in the URL for the pages to link correctly (else the 404 shows).

All groups are fine but one. I have a group called 'site' where all misc pages are listed.

Is there a way to have only this folder removed similarly to index.php with the htaccess?

Thanks

Comment: Here's some good tips on what you can do: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/559/removing-part-of-ee-urls-with-htaccess-or-via-other-methods?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Depending on usage, you may want to just use the [Pages Module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/pages/index.html), which lets you configure custom URLs and connect them to the template of your choice. I use this quite a lot in my setups.

Comment: ...Or Structure :) http://buildwithstructure.com

Comment: Sure if you like. Depends on how extensively you need the pages.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually hiding index.php with .htaccess, you're adding it (hidden) to the URL a person accesses. So you're not going to be removing (hiding) the template group, you'll be adding it the urls that require it. And that I think is the problem - knowing what URL's require the addition.

The only way I can think of is to hard code the template segments to identify when it should be added:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(sitemap\.xml|sitemap_index\.xml|fb-page)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/site/$1 [L]
```

In the above example I have 3 templates in the 'site' group I want to be accessible directly:

- sitemap.xml
- sitemap_index.xml
- fb-page