# Hide template_group segment in URL

Tags: tags, segments

I've seen this question in Google but the link ended up dead on the Ellislab page.

I have a not too big site which resides all in one template group.

Is it possible to remove the template group from the url so instead of  `http://domain.com/site/contact`
it should be `http://domain.com/contact`

I already stripped the index.php via .htaccess

I once removed the template folder by linking to subpages with: `{path='contact'}` instead of `{path='site/contact'}` but I'm not sure if this is a good practice and doesn't mess up the site in one way or another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few days ago there was a question about Strict URLs in EE, enabling Strict url you have option to link directly to template jumping over template_group [What does "Enable Strict URLs" really mean?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/211/what-does-enable-strict-urls-really-mean) 
does this solves your issue?

Comment: Thanks this url_schematic does really lighten up some things.

Answer (score 2):

Using `{path=contact}` to link to a template in `site/contact` is definitely a safe practice.  Is it a "good" practice? There's no real downside to it, so I'd say yes.

There's also nothing 'bad' about having multiple template groups (within reason!), so you could also use `contact/index` as your template and link to it with `{path=contact}`

Comment: I guess your right. If I compare the behaviour of the links in the url schematic this should not cause any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The default template group should not be showing in the first segment. Has this been set for the `site` template group?

Typically on small sites I just hard code the main navigation.

Comment: It will do if you've got 'enable strict URLs' on.