# Template issue when Strict URLs enabled

Tags: ee2, templates, channel

I have a problem with one template after enabling Strict URLs - it returns 404 instead displaying content from the channel named News. The URL to open that template is like http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/news/

Template code:

```
    {embed="includes/header_main"}
    {embed="includes/header_two_column"}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
            <div id="content_main">
                      {if segment_2 == ''}
                         {exp:channel:entries channel="news"}
                            <h1 class="orange">{title}</h1>
                            {news_summary}
                            <a href="/index.php{page_uri}">Read more</a>
                            <br /><br /><br />
                         {/exp:channel:entries}
                    {if:else}
                         {exp:channel:entries channel="news"}
                            <h2 class="bigorange">{title}</h2>
                            {news_body}
                            <p><a href="/index.php/nm">Back to news</a></p>
                         {/exp:channel:entries}
                    {/if}
                    </div>
            <div id="content_sub_buttons">
                <div style="background-image: url(/uploads/images/doc_photo.png); width:212px; height: 199px;">
                <div style="padding-top: 12px; padding-left: 15px;">
                {exp:ce_cache:escape}
                {exp:random_number min="1" max="6"}
                <img src="/uploads/images/kids/{random_number_0}.png">
                {/exp:random_number}
                {/exp:ce_cache:escape}
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        {embed="includes/footer"}
```

Any clue why is not loading that template?

Thanks

Comment: Please, what is the URL you're trying to open?

Comment: An example of URL added to the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strict URL is working exactly how it is supposed to for you. From the [EE blog](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.6-and-strict-urls):

> With Strict URLs disabled, it’s possible to visit http://example.com/about-us/ and view that content. But you can also visit http://example.com/site/about-us/ and get the exact same content. This flexibility can be advantageous, but it comes with a price: dual availability can cause search engines to lower the content’s ranking.
>
> With ExpressionEngine 2.6 and up, Strict URLs will be enabled by default in new installations. Using the same example, http://example.com/site/about-us/ is the only valid URL for that content. Visiting http://example.com/about-us/ with Strict URLs enabled will trigger ExpressionEngine’s defined 404 behavior.

If you have `site/news` as a template and strict URLs enabled, you can't access the news template with `index.php/news`. You have to have `index.php/site/news`.

**UPDATE**

Can you see if this does anything for you? Change your complex conditional to two simple conditionals:

```
{if segment_2 == ''}news home{/if}
{if segment_2 != ''}news listing{/if}
```

Comment: Duplicated? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/211/what-does-enable-strict-urls-really-mean

Comment: Well, take a look here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/235749/ For me index.php/meet-us working with enabled Strict URL

Comment: @Robson - it is not duplicated. I have read your link a day ago, but doesn't help with only _one_ not working template when Strict URL enabled

Comment: @JackTheKnife hmm. how is your meet-us template set-up in EE?

Comment: Updated answer with something else to at least check out for testing.

Comment: @Stephen: meet-us template is in a same group 'site' as news template and all other templates. It looks similar to template presented above just pulling data from another channel as a page URL (from posts settings to display that page with meet-us template)

Comment: @Stephen: regarding your update - I have added both if statements and news template goes to 404. For me it looks like if page doesn't exits as URL (step 1 from a "diagram") then is not pulling template from default group (step 2 from a "diagram")

Comment: I read through your old EE forums thread. There was probably something that went wrong in the update from EE1. What happens if you create a new template in the `site` template group? How does it behave? If it works according to the rules in my original answer, then copy over the `news` template code to it and see what happens. Change `segment_2` to `segment_3` if you have /site in `segment_1`.

Comment: @JackTheKnife, when you enable *Make the index template in this group your site's home page*, just the **index** file of this template group is made accessible **without** any url segments. All others templates still needs the template group as segment_1, except in case you set the URLs on Pages Module.

So, instead of "site.group/meet-us" and "site.group/news", use "meet-us.group/index.html" and "news.group/index.html". This way, you don't need the pages module to make the URLs "/news" and "/meet-us" to work.

Comment: @Robson - all pages have set the URLs on Pages Module that's why are working without typing 'site.group'

Comment: @Stephen - Imo it can be that something went wrong with migration from EE1 to EE2 but not clue what. Anyway, got it solved using .htaccess and RewriteRule only for that one particular template ;)

Comment: As all above comments to that answer are helpful I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In your example of `http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/news/` you need to make sure that `news` is set as you default template group and that it contains a template called `index`. Otherwise you have to explicitly declare the template_group/template in the URL.

Comment: Well, it looks like I have a problem with default template group, which has all-in-one catch-all /site/ group for all templates, including index and news. When I use `http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/site/news/` it works as should. In that case I have used .htaccess RewriteRule to point to proper URL for that one case.

Comment: So `site` is your *Default Group* and you have ticked *Make the index template in this group your site's home page?*? If not then you'll need to do this or specify the template along with the template group.

Comment: Which version of EE is this btw?

Comment: Correct - 'site' is a default template group and 'index' template is a home page there.

Comment: I'm on EE 2.5.4