# RSS feed template and 404 Not Found

Tags: templates

I have created RSS feed template (named as 'feed') to pull data from the blog channel and it looks like

```
{preload_replace:master_channel_name="blog"}
{exp:rss:feed channel="{master_channel_name}"}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}"?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">

    <channel>

    <title><![CDATA[{channel_name}]]></title>
    <link>{channel_url}</link>
    <description>{channel_description}</description>
    <dc:language>{channel_language}</dc:language>
    <dc:creator>{email}</dc:creator>
    <dc:rights>Copyright {gmt_date format="%Y"}</dc:rights>
    <dc:date>{gmt_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
    <admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://expressionengine.com/" />

{exp:channel:entries channel="{master_channel_name}" limit="10" dynamic_start="on" disable="member_data|pagination"}
    <item>
      <title><![CDATA[{title}]]></title>
      <link>{title_permalink='site/index'}</link>
      <guid>{title_permalink='site/index'}#When:{gmt_entry_date format="%H:%i:%sZ"}</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[{summary}{body}]]></description>
      <dc:subject><![CDATA[{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/categories}]]></dc:subject>
      <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
    </item>
{/exp:channel:entries}

    </channel>
</rss>

{/exp:rss:feed}
```

but when I will refer browser to feed url like http://www.mydomain.com/feed I'm getting 404 Not Found.

Any clue what can be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing it's just the way your templates are set up. Is your template group called `feed.group`? And the template itself called `feed.xml`?

If that's the case it will need to be accessed at `http://example.com/feed/feed`. Or you can change your RSS template to be `feed.group/index.xml` so you can access it at `http://example.com/feed` as desired.

If this misses the boat, please update your question with a little more information on your template setup and I can try to be more helpful.

UPDATE based on your comments:

Since you have strict URLs enabled you will not be able to access the default template group's templates without also including the default template group's name in the path. See this [EllisLab blog post](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.6-and-strict-urls) as well as [this answer on Stack Exchange](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/229/22) for more info.

So in your case, since the feed is in your default template group, `site.group`, the URL you need to use when Strict URLs is enabled is `http://example.com/site/feed`.

Comment: This is right. The URL will have both the template group name and template name.

For example, I often create an RSS template named rss in the blog template group, and my feed URL is then:

http://example.com/blog/rss

Comment: OK, I have found that http://www.childrensmedgroup.com/index.php/site/feed works but links withing feed are not correct :\

Comment: JackTheKnife, Do you have Strict URLs enabled? Are you using .htaccess to remove index.php?

Comment: @AlexKendrick - yes, Strict URLs are enabled. .htaccess has rewrite rule to get URLs without index.php to work.

Comment: That you have Strict URLs enabled (which is a good thing generally) explains why you are getting a 404 when trying `example.com/feed`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @AlexKendrick As I have posted few lines above I'm able to get access feed not using Strict URL but links from RSS are not correct. See link above.

Comment: It looks like URL based on 'URL title' is not working but only 'Pages URI'

Comment: Yes, if you are using the Pages module for those entries then {page_url} is a better way to generate a path to those entries. You may want to update your original post or start a new message since this is a separate issue from what you originally asked about.

Comment: I have marked answer above as correct one due to Strict URLs issue.